# Are there any file download components for joomla that are MVC and Bootstrap?

Tags: joomla-3.x, component

I've tried pretty much every free file download component I could find, all of them are flawed to the point where I dont see them as the answer for my site.

I would like something that is coded with Joomla 3x and future expansions in mind, therefore MVC. Would also like Bootstrap 3 since that is what the rest of my site is running.

So far I have tried jdownloads (seriously aging and not MVC or BS3)
Phoca Downloads (very very poorly written)
T-Download Store (this is the closest to what I was looking for but development froze and support is non existent and current release is extremely buggy)

At this point I am open to paid components, but since there is no real way for me to see the code before purchase and demos are pretty limited, I really have no way of knowing how well these are truly written.

Other than my primary architectural desires, would also like to be able to have version history for each product downloadable, tagging (mainly for my plugins to illustrate compatible software versions).

Comment: I genuinely despise jDownloads so no comment on that one! I've never looked too much into the Phoca Download code so can't comment on the quality, however if I rightly remember when I used it a couple of years back, it was easy to use and fairly flexible. Having looked at the folder structure, it is MVC and according to their site, it uses Bootstrap 3. Other than that, DOCman is commercial, but they say you're entitled to a 30 day money back, guaranteed, if you're not happy.

Comment: Phoca is the forerunner right now, but not because its good, its just the least bad. Everything about the code in phoca makes it look like it was designed to be a standalone product then was "hacked" into joomla as an afterthought. Its MVC only in the loosest of terms and rarely takes advantage of any joomla framework but instead duplicates much of the code that joomla already does and typically in better form.

Comment: Have you considered forking it?

Comment: its alwayse an option, but a very time consuming one lol. If these were billable hours for a client then i'd definitely just fork and re-code it myself, but as it is this is for one of my sites therefore cannot spend that much time on it, Thats why at this point im happy to just pay for one that is already properly written.